# How to check the status of an image using docker-java library

Tags: java, image, docker

I am trying to check if the image is running or not using the docker-Java library(https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java). I can get the list of all running images using the following

```
List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd().exec();
```

Is there a way to check the status of the image if its running or not using the docker-java library?

Comment: What docker-Java libraryare you actually running? There are a few https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/

Comment: Updated Answer (Found using github) https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/3ebe8ca8eabdef9b512570fe8b60f1b1234df9c6/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/command/EventsCmdImplTest.java Line 65 It gives more information how they used it.

Comment: I want to be able to use the image name to see if a container is running with that image

Answer (score 0):

You can see the events for a certain image by using the eventsCmd().withImages() method.

```
dockerClient.eventsCmd().withImages('ImageName').exec(eventCallback);
```

I have not tested the code, but it's method is located [here](https://github.com/meehanman/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/model/Filters.java)

Comment: was looking for something that returns status based on the String - image name

Comment: Does this work? Check the link (https://github.com/meehanman/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/model/Filters.java) for more information